# IPad MBProgressHUD does it support device orientation change?

Tags: ios, ipad, device-orientation, mbprogresshud

I have been using MBProgressHUD for displaying hud. Everything works ok in portrait mode, but when i change device orientation, hud is not rotated properly?

Is there some property to set hud the right way?

Comment: Is this issue resolved? `MBProgressHUD` supports device orientation changes. If the issue still persists, can you post your codes?

Comment: To be honest haven't used it quite in a while... i remember using default spinner at end